# Can I retrieve the user32.dll getlastinputtime from a system service

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, user32

I am trying to write a system service that can detect whether the user is active and then launch a process if not.  I am using a service because I want this to work if the user is logged in or not.  I have been trying to hook into the user32.dll API and retrieve the time since last user input.  However the integer being returned is always 0 so I don't think it is working correctly.  Is this not possible when running as a system service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may like to use `getlastinputinfo` on user32.dll

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Shared Function GetLastInputInfo(ByRef plii As LASTINPUTINFO) As Boolean
End Function

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Structure LASTINPUTINFO
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> _
    Public cbSize As Integer
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> _
    Public dwTime As Integer
End Structure
```

[LASTINPUTINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646272%28VS.85%29.aspx) on MSDN

Comment: Thanks regexhacks. This is exactly what I was attempting to do but it doesn't seem to work. My code is slightly different however here is what I have: `Private Structure PLASTINPUTINFO Dim cbSize As Integer Dim dwTime As Integer End Structure Private Declare Function GetLastInputInfo Lib "user32.dll" _ (ByRef plii As PLASTINPUTINFO) As Boolean`

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting.  I don't know how to put the code with line breaks in this mini-markdown format.  Hopefully you can tell where they go?